# How to pass String in Querystring Parameter in @Html.ActionLink

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, razor

I have written following code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditPost", new { id = item.PostID })
```

It displays URL like `.../Post/EditPost/32`
but actually I want to display it like `...../Post/EditPost?ID=32`

How is it possible in Razor View???

Answer (score 1):

The URL construct is generally dictated by the route, if you want to force it to use the query string then just remove any notion of a parameter from it e.g.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "EditPostRoute",
    "Post/EditPost",
    new { controller = "Edit", action = "EditPost" }
);
```

Your `@Html.ActionLink` code should generate `.../Post/EditPost?ID=32`.

Answer (score 0):

Change Action Edit parameter from `int` to `string`. Then it will display as you want

```
public ActionResult Edit(string ID)
{
     =======
     =======
}

@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditPost", new { ID = item.PostID },null)
```

Another solution 
 remove `id = UrlParameter.Optional` from the `Global.asax/Route Table`